# How to keep Twitter Bootstrap customization with Bower?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, customization, bower

I'm working in a project with [yeoman](http://yeoman.io) which includes [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) for automation and [bower](http://twitter.github.com/bower/) for client-side package management. One of the dependencies of my project is [SASS twitter-bootstrap](https://github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap).

In other projects, in which I manually managed the updates of dependencies, I changed [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) values directly in the Bootstrap `variables.less` (`_variables.scss`) file and extend it in `main.less` files under the project own `css` folder. I did the same here, but when I installed other packages with Bower it overrode everything (I "un-.gitignored" my components' folder, thanks God)

What's the best way to customize [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) outside the components' folder so it won't happen again?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should never modify the contents of the `bower_components` folder. We'll make sure to make that clearer.

As for your question. Copy the `_variables.scss` file from the `bower_components` folder to eg. `app/styles`, then import it into your `main.scss`, or whatever it's named, above the import statement for bootstrap. This will result in your custom file overriding the default variables.

Comment: Now that you mention the @import-overrides trick it seems pretty obvious XD

Comment: I don't know if something has changed but I found that placing the import statement for the overriding _variables file **above** the Bootstrap import worked whilst placing it below didn't.

Comment: does that mean that when using bootstrap as a bower component _variables.scss is the only file I should overwrite? What if I need to change something else than what is in that file? Or maybe if I need to change something else I might not even need bootstrap at all?

Comment: @sindre-sorhus - what to do if I don't want to include all bootstrap components in final css output https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss

Comment: I understand now that why we must use `!default` statement if needed. Thanks.