# Yeoman / Bower / Gulp Auto Compiling SASS and Refreshing on File Change

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I can't get Yeoman / Bower / Gulp and the gulp-webapp generator to auto compile  SASS changes made to the Bootstrap _variables.scss file and reload.

Basically changes done to files in this path: 
/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/

I spent some time tweaking the gulpfile.js and managed to get autoreload to work on changes made to any files in the path above; however, it doesn't recompile the sass files. The only way to recompile is using the "gulp" command but that would be counter productive.

I am stumped after many hours, could someone please help shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project by design is set up to only watch for changes to your personal style files in the `app/styles/` directory and it's sub directories.

The idea of modifying files in the `/bower_components` directory is generally considered a bad practice. If you were to accidentally run `bower update`, it would overwrite all of you changes to your modified bower files.

Instead you could use sass to `@import` the bootstrap `.scss` files into your `main.scss` file from `/bower_components`. then you can redefine all of the styles you want using these [sass variables](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss)

Comment: That makes sense regarding the bad practice but all I would need to do is add back in the _custom.scss file back into the _bootstrap.scss. As long as "bower update" doesn't delete files it should work.

I was having issues importing using my method so coincidentally I am doing what you suggested at the moment. I am able to import the _variables.scss file into my main.scss; however, I am unable to overwrite the bootstrap variable "$brand-success:" to yellow. Are you able to get your way to work without a problem?

Comment: Oh I just realized you can't override an imported variable with a value after the @import line - it has to be before. If it is after it has to be either another $variable: $variable or .class { color: $variable; } but not $variable: color;.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773583/can-i-override-sass-variables-after-they-have-been-imported

Comment: _"Copy the _variables.scss file from the bower_components folder to eg. app/styles, then import it into your main.scss, or whatever it's named, above the import statement for bootstrap. This will result in your custom file overriding the default variables."_ as per this thread [Custom Bootstrap with Bower](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385705/how-to-keep-twitter-bootstrap-customization-with-bower)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Not sure if it is the best way of doing but it works.

In the gulp.watch section of the code (line 98)

```
gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
gulp.watch('app/fonts/**/*', ['fonts']);
gulp.watch('bower.json', ['wiredep', 'fonts']);
```

I duplicated the first line and just added the path to the Bootstrap .scss files.

```
gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
gulp.watch('bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
gulp.watch('app/fonts/**/*', ['fonts']);
```

Now whenever I change say the $btn-default-bg in the _variables.scss file it automatically recompiles.

The idea is I can add a _[name].scss to the original Bootstrap SASS list and it will be included in the distributed version.