# Proper way to customize Bower-installed components

Tags: git, twitter-bootstrap, npm, bower

When I use Bower to install something like `bootstrap-sass-official`, it installs it in the `bower_components` directory. A component like Bootstrap allows for customization by editing the file `bower_components/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss`. In this case, you simple pick and choose which parts of Bootstrap you want to use for your project.

It is well known that it is most efficient and best practice to leave packages and components like `./bower_components`, `./vendor`, `./node_modules` etc out of source control. But the problem with this is that when others download your source and install the bower dependencies, your customizations are never installed.

So, assuming that you are following best practices and keeping `bower_components` out of source control, where is the best place to customize a component like Bootstrap? Simply copy `_bootstrap.scss` to a source-controlled directory and customize it there? Or is there a more elegant approach?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct in saying that the most elegant solution is to copy the `_bootstrap.scss` file to your project structure.  You could then remove the bootstrap components that you wish to exclude, and modify the paths of the remaining components to point to your `bower_components` directory.  In this way you get full customization over the library while only maintaining a single file.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15420353/2517147) might also be helpful to those looking into this issue.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. Unfortunately this approach kind of defeats the purpose of easily installable components via bower. Oh well. Thank you,